# Get only street names from Overpass

Tags: overpass-api, nominatim, overpass-turbo

Is it possible to get a list of street names (without house numbers) by bounding box with Overpass or Nominatim?
I got this query, but it is with house numbers so the responce JSON is big

```
[out:json][timeout:25];
// gather results
(

  node["addr:street"]({{bbox}});
  way["addr:street"]({{bbox}});
  relation["addr:street"]({{bbox}});
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Answer (score 1):

See our Overpass by Example guide on how to extract street names for an area: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#List_of_streets

*NB: It's the first hit if you search for "overpass street names" in a well known search engine.*